# Python socket client Post parameters

Tags: python, sockets, http, post

Fir let me clear **I don't want to to use higher level APIs, I only want to use socket programming**

I have wrote following program to connect to server using POST request.

```
import socket
import binascii

host = "localhost"
port = 9000
message = "POST /auth HTTP/1.1\r\n"
parameters = "userName=Ganesh&password=pass\r\n"
contentLength = "Content-Length: " + str(len(parameters))
contentType = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"

finalMessage = message + contentLength + contentType + "\r\n"
finalMessage = finalMessage + parameters
finalMessage = binascii.a2b_qp(finalMessage)


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.sendall(finalMessage)

print(s.recv(1024))
```

I checked online how POST request is created.

Somehow Paramters are not getting passed to the server. Do I have to add or remove "\r\n" in between the request?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Ganesh.

Comment: Here's code example: [Make https POST request using sockets.](https://gist.github.com/zed/1841962#file-http-post-socket-py)

Answer (score 15):

This line `finalMessage = binascii.a2b_qp(finalMessage)` is certainly wrong, so you should remove the line completely, another problem is that there is no new-line missing after `Content-Length`. In this case the request sent to the socket is (I am showing the `CR` and `LF` characters here as `\r\n`, but also splitting lines for clarity):

```
POST /auth HTTP/1.1\r\n
Content-Length: 31Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
\r\n
userName=Ganesh&password=pass\r\n
```

So obviously this does not make much sense to the web server.

---

But even after adding a newline and removing `a2b_qp`, there is still the problem is that you are *not* [talking `HTTP/1.1`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) there; the request must have a `Host` header for HTTP/1.1 (RFC 2616 14.23):

> A client **MUST include a Host header** field in all HTTP/1.1 request
>   messages . If the requested URI does not include an Internet host name
>   for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST be
>   given with an empty value. An HTTP/1.1 proxy MUST ensure that any
>   request message it forwards does contain an appropriate Host header
>   field that identifies the service being requested by the proxy. **All
>   Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request)
>   status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header
>   field.**

Also you do not support chunked requests and persistent connections, keepalives or anything, so you must do `Connection: close` (RFC 2616 14.10):

> HTTP/1.1 applications that do not support persistent connections **MUST**
>   include the "close" connection option in every message.

Thus, any `HTTP/1.1` server that would still respond normally to your messages without `Host:` header is also broken.

This the data that you should send to the socket with that request:

```
POST /auth HTTP/1.1\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
Content-Length: 29\r\n
Host: localhost:9000\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
\r\n
userName=Ganesh&password=pass
```

Note that you'd *not* add the `\r\n` in the body anymore (thus the length of body 29). Also you should read the response to find out whatever the error is that you're getting.

---

On Python 3 the working code would say:

```
host = "localhost"
port = 9000

headers = """\
POST /auth HTTP/1.1\r
Content-Type: {content_type}\r
Content-Length: {content_length}\r
Host: {host}\r
Connection: close\r
\r\n"""

body = 'userName=Ganesh&password=pass'                                 
body_bytes = body.encode('ascii')
header_bytes = headers.format(
    content_type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    content_length=len(body_bytes),
    host=str(host) + ":" + str(port)
).encode('iso-8859-1')

payload = header_bytes + body_bytes

# ...

socket.sendall(payload)
```

Comment: @Antti Haapala,  Thank you very much. This solved my problem. And pardon my HTTP knowledge.

One more thing, that call  binascii.a2b_qp() is necessary as socket does not receive String as input.